# plotting from a loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, line, curve

I get some strange problem in my matlab code, this is a part of my code:

```
for k=1:length(box11)
    num_pts1(k)=sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)));
    size1=sum(length(find(box11(:,:)>0)));
    perc1(k)=(num_pts1(k)/size1)*100;
end
plot(delta,perc1(k),'*')
```

However, the problem is that I get perc1 fixed in my plot. so I see a straight line in the graph. but I would like to have different numbers which give a curve line to me..
plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, any help :( !!!

Comment: Two things are unclear to me: The result you are trying to get vs. what you get and what `box11` is. Please be clearer on that. (Attaching the plot you get might help)

Comment: Hi, this is box11:
box11=flipud(full(sparse(delta11,Sref11,delta11))); where delta11 and Sref11 are two matrixces 51*1

Comment: Do you mean `plot(delta,perc1,'*')` ? otherwise you are just plotting a single point, `perc1(k)` where `k` is `legnth(box11)`. Also what is `delta`?

Comment: the code which I added gives me a straight line, which means that k is fixed.. while it should be a curve because k is changing every loop.. hope that I could explain it now :) !!

Comment: No help until now :( :( :(

Answer (score 0):

You should recall that `length` returns the length of an array. So, in the instruction

```
num_pts1(k)=sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)));
```

the operator `sum` acts on a scalar (which equals the length of the array `find(box11(:,k)>0)`), and not on an array. The same holds true for the instruction

```
size1=sum(length(find(box11(:,:)>0)));
```

So, if the length of `find(box11(:,k)>0)` does not change with `k`, then your `perc1` will keep constant.

Comment: unfortunately, didnt get what you mean :(.. what should I change then... thanks a lot

Comment: Perhaps you do not need `length` in the two instructions involving `num_pts1` and `size1`. Before proceeding further, please read some introductory tutorial/book on Matlab.

Comment: mmmmm :(, the problem still there :(..
and I need length to be there

Comment: No help until now :( :( :(

Comment: Is there any reason to have `sum(length(find(box11(:,k)>0)))`? `length` returns a number, why do you `sum` a number?

Comment: Because I would like to know how many points there is in each columns

Comment: Then you do not need `sum`.